# interpretation of covariance result matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to make sense out of reading the result of a covariance matrix. I know if the resulting signs are both >0 then it means the arrays are moving in the same direction.

```
x = np.array([[10,39,19,23,28],
              [43,13,32,21,20],
              [15,16,22,85,15]])

print(np.cov(x))
```

How to interpret this result?

```
[[ 115.7  -120.55  -18.6 ]
 [-120.55  138.7   -76.35]
 [ -18.6   -76.35  933.3 ]]
```

Edit: in addition to [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2550541/luca-cappelletti)'s answer, I've added a simple line graph to help visualise the spread (variance) and movement (covariance) of data.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Covariance Matrix

A [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is a *nxn* symmetric matrix where *n* is the number of columns of the matrix you are starting with and shows how the vector variables *covariate*, meaning how they tend to move in respect to one another.

### Components

On the main diagonal you find the variance of the vector and on all other coordinates you find the covariance since var(X) = cov(X, X).

### Positive and negative coefficients

In the main diagonal no values can be negative since they represent the variance of a vector. On any other position, the covariance can be obtained as a product of two [standard deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) (that are always non-negative) (*s*(X) and *s*(Y)) and the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) *p* that instead varies between [-1, 1]: this is the coefficient that makes the values positive or negative.

*cov*(X, Y) = *p*(X,Y)*s*(X)*s*(Y)

There are three possibilities:

1. ***p*(X, Y)==0:** no correlation between the vectors.
2. ***p*(X,Y)>0:** positive correlation, meaning that when the vector X grows so does the magnitude of Y.
3. ***p*(X,Y)<0:** negative correlation, meaning that when the vector X grows, the magnitude of Y decreases.

The standard deviations effect on the coefficients in the matrices is "just" magnitude, meaning they highlight more correlation when the standard deviation of the data points is higher.

### Visualization

To better visualise the content of the matrix I am using the [`heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) function from the [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) python package. Also I
 have added the correlation matrix to better compare the results.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([[10,39,19,23,28],
            [43,13,32,21,20],
            [15,16,22,85,15]])

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.heatmap(np.cov(x), 
        annot=True,
        cbar = False,
        fmt="0.2f",
        cmap="YlGnBu",
        xticklabels=range(len(x)),
        yticklabels=range(len(x)))
plt.title("Covariance matrix")
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
sns.heatmap(np.corrcoef(x), 
        annot=True,
        cbar = False,
        fmt="0.2f",
        cmap="YlGnBu",
        xticklabels=range(len(x)),
        yticklabels=range(len(x)))
plt.title("Correlation matrix")
```

**Output:**

[image: Correlation and covariance matrices]

### Interpretation

The third vector, when compared with the others, has an exceptionally high variance. All the vectors have a **negative correlations**, in particular the vector 1 and 2 that are **strongly** correlated. The vectors 1 and 3 are the least correlated.